# How to trigger a Journey API Entry event with AMPscript and server-side JavaScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I want to input the user's mailbox on the cloud page, click the send button, and the user's mailbox will be recorded in DE, and then trigger a journey to send mail to the user in this DE. The DE part has been implemented and a new journey has been created. But how can you trigger the journey by clicking the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a sample code that contains a form and upon submission adds the contact to a journey:

```
%%[
SET @Submit = RequestParameter("Submit")
IF @Submit != "Success" THEN
]%%
<h2>Email:</h2>
<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="GET">
<label for="email">Email address:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="yes">
<button type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Success">Submit</button>
</form>
%%[
ENDIF
]%%
%%[
SET @email = RequestParameter("email")
IF @email != "" THEN
]%%
    
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {

var email = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("email");

    //authenticate to get access token
    var authEndpoint = 'https://xxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/&#39;  //provide API endpoint
    var payload = {
        client_id: "xxxxxx",    //pass Client ID
        client_secret: "xxxxxx",    //pass Client Secret
        grant_type: "client_credentials" 
    };
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token'
    var contentType = 'application/json'

    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token
        var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url
    };

    //make api call to inject contact to a journey  
    if (email != null && accessToken != null) {
       
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
        var jsonBody = {
            "ContactKey": email,
            "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-xxxxxxx",    //provide journey EVENT DEFINITION KEY
            "Data": {
                "email_field": email
            }
        };

        var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + "/interaction/v1/events";

        var fireEntryEvent = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, Stringify(jsonBody), headerNames, headerValues);
   
      if (fireEntryEvent.StatusCode == 201) {
        Write("Success");
      }
    };
} catch (error) {
    Write("Error");
}
</script>
%%[
ENDIF
]%%
```

You’ll need to add the API credentials and the journey api event key to the above.

For a full tutorial see here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/04/07/add-subscribers-to-a-journey-from-a-cloudpage-using-fire-entry-event/

Comment: I tried the following code, but it didn't work. I replaced all the relevant parameters, but after clicking the submit button, the journey didn't trigger. But I tested the parameters in postman to be feasible.

Comment: I just tested myself and it works fine, can you try logging the `accessToken` and the `fireEntryEvent.StatusCode` to narrow down where the problem is?

Comment: I know where the problem is, var email = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("email"); This code should be placed before if (email!=null&&accessToken!=null). Otherwise, you cannot enter the conditional judgment and execute the code in the if statement. I changed this code to successfully execute and achieve the desired effect. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for catching that and please remember to accept the answer if it helped!