# How to send a POST request to a URL with Params using ampscript on the cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I can successfully obtain an accesstoken by sending a request in Postman like the following image, but I don't know how to use ampscript to send post requests like the following on the cloud page. I used to use httppost() to send requests, but it doesn't have a Content Type header value. I don't seem to be able to use httppost(). Which function should I use to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280354/how-to-generate-access-token-using-ampscript

Comment: Zuzanna provided a complete code, showing how to use a combination of ampscript and SSJS, in your [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396013/how-to-trigger-a-journey-api-entry-event-with-ampscript-and-server-side-javascri) - This includes contentType header as well

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem because this post request doesn't use payload, and the header is not "application/json". I want to use ampscript to implement this link on cloudpage.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_basic_info_get.htm

Comment: Am I reading this correctly you want to use the SFMC token to authorize a request to a Sales Cloud org?

Comment: Yes,the entire process is similar to the following link. https://salesforcejandj.com/getting-record-details-from-salesforce-using-the-rest-api If you use httppost, the format is HTTPPost (URL endpoint used to post content, Content Type header value, Content to include in POST request). However, the problem now is that when you send a post request to obtain a token, it doesn't have a Content Type header value. Simply add params to the url.

Comment: Why don't you do it with SSJS?

Comment: Because this function needs to be implemented in the code that originally placed ampscript. However, how can SSJS be implemented?

Comment: You can mix the two without any problems, see my reply to your question about JB. Also, this article: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2022/09/06/passing-variable-values-between-ampscript-server-side-javascript-and-client-side-javascript/